# SMP operating system that had been "proven" to be bug free?

Tags: history, multi-tasking

Many years ago someone told me about a historical SMP operating system (or program?) that had been all but proven to be bug free (or something close to this). But yet turned out to have bugs that were discovered as CPUs with more cores, than initially tested/developed on, came out. Can anyone provide a source of this?

Comment: What is `big free`? (Read the title carefully).  A play on words of  `bug free`? Or maybe it was written by a bot?

Comment: Are you thinking of RTOSs like VxWorks or OSE?

Comment: As a student, one exercise was to deliver a small application with a correctness proof. I delivered one version with correctness proof which didn’t work, and one version which worked, but the correctness proof failed.

Comment: @C8H10N4O2 yes as I recall it was something like that